# Unity 2019.2.15f1 videoPlayer.loopPointReached not working on Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-video-player

I have a videoplayer in my scene which works well on the editor but when I build and deploy it on my device(Android 6.0) the video plays but when it has finished playing the event videoPlayer.LoopPointReached is not being called. On the editor everything works fine but on the android device the event is not being called.

```
 videoPlayer.errorReceived += HandleVideoError;
 videoPlayer.started += HandleStartedEvent;
 videoPlayer.seekCompleted += HandleSeekCompleted;
 videoPlayer.loopPointReached += EndReached;

 void EndReached(VideoPlayer video)
 {
    // show cube
    cubeObject.SetActive(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are saying is true about `EndReached()` not being called on Android device, then its probably a bug in Unity. You should file a bug report so as to fix it soon. Also how and where are you writing this piece of code `videoPlayer.loopPointReached += EndReached;` in your script?
In the meantime, you can use the video clip's frame count to determine the end of the video;

```
void Update()
{
  if(videoPlayer.frame == videoPlayer.frameCount)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your video clip's frame suggestion but no success. The code videoPlayer.loopPointReached += EndReached; is placed in the start() function.

Comment: @StephenMutua then I am assuming that the video bug is in your version of Unity. Please report it.

Comment: I have reported the bug but no response. I have also tried to test with a different version of unity (2018.4.14) but still no changes..

Comment: Oh if you have tried different version of Unity and still it does not work then its definitely a problem with your device, you sure it works well on editor? Could you also try on a different device? Also, does the video play completely in your device?

Comment: The video plays to the end but after playing is finished the event videoPlayer.loopPointReached is not being invoked..2 days ago it was working but it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that it was the video that I was playing which had low frame rate. It had 25 frames/second but I converted it to 30 frames/second and it now works on the device.

Anyone with such an issue can try my solution.